# Linux dynamic link error with wxWebConnect

Tags: c++, linux, linker, wxpython, shared-libraries

I use and develop wxWebConnect and Python bindings for it (see http://github.com/jonmmorgan/wxwebconnect/ and http://github.com/jonmmorgan/pywebconnect/).  These have built on Linux before.  However, when support for XRC handlers was added Python programs crash when loading the .so file with the error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN22wxWebControlXmlHandlerC1Ev
```

The library has been built and runs correctly on both Mac OS X and Windows since the change was made to support XRC.

The cause of this problem seems to be that the constructor for the class wxWebControlXmlHandler (see https://github.com/jonmmorgan/wxwebconnect/blob/master/xh_webcontrol.cpp) is not being included in the built shared object file.  Running nm on xh_webcontrol.o shows that the symbol is in the text section of that object file, and that object file is one of the object files that is linked into the shared object.  However, running nm on the shared object file shows that it is undefined, and that is what causes the crash.

I can't understand why the constructor is not being included in the shared object file, since it is obviously required (and I know the constructor is invoked in webcontrol.cpp). Is there a good reason for this?  Is there anything I can or should do to force the constructor to be included in the shared object file and exported?

**Commands used to build (setuptools generated):**

---

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/gtk/wc_wrap.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/gtk/wc_wrap.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/webconnect/dom.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/dom.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/webconnect/nsimpl.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/nsimpl.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/webconnect/promptservice.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/promptservice.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/webconnect/protocolhandler.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/protocolhandler.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/webconnect/webcontrol.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/webcontrol.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/webconnect/webframe.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/webframe.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/webconnect/webprefs.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/webprefs.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/webconnect/xh_webcontrol.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/xh_webcontrol.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -Icontrib/wc -Icontrib/wc/webconnect -I/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/wc/pyprotocolhandler.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/pyprotocolhandler.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/gtk/wc_wrap.o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/dom.o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/nsimpl.o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/promptservice.o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/protocolhandler.o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/webcontrol.o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/webframe.o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/webprefs.o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/webconnect/xh_webcontrol.o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-i686-2.6/contrib/wc/pyprotocolhandler.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lwx_gtk2u_richtext-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_html-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_core-2.8 -lwx_baseu_xml-2.8 -lwx_baseu_net-2.8 -lwx_baseu-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8 -o /home/jmmorgan/wxwebconnect/wxPython-src-2.8.11.0/wxPython/wx/_wc.so -pthread -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Comment: Could you show the makefile used for linking? I couldn't find one building shared library.

Comment: I use Python setuptools.  I will put in the commands it used.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your object files in `-Wl,--whole-archive`  `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` section.

`man ld`:

> **--whole-archive**
>              For each archive mentioned on the command line after the --whole-archive option, include every object file in the archive in the
>              link, rather than searching the archive for the required object files.  This is normally used to turn an archive file into a shared
>              library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting shared library.  This option may be used more than once.
>
> Two notes when using this option from gcc: First, gcc doesn't know about this option, so you have to use -Wl,-whole-archive.
>              Second, don't forget to use -Wl,-no-whole-archive after your list of archives, because gcc will add its own list of archives to your
>              link and you may not want this flag to affect those as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference.  The symbol is still defined in the object file, but undefined in the library file.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment: it seems I was linking with the wrong version of the library, and so it still didn't work.

Comment: @Jonathan Try linking with minimal set of options (removing -pthread, -Wl,-O1 and -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions). You could add -Wl,-no-undefined option - maybe it will provide some additional info. Check also if you don't have some visibility options set in the code declaring/defining this constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to comment on this again.  It is actually linking and working fine now.  It's possible that I was installing an old version of the library accidentally (though that still doesn't sound quite right).  Anyway, thanks for the help, but no amount of help will help when I'm not even doing what I think I'm doing :).